# SDL_RenderDrawPoint() performance is slow and takes too much memory

Tags: c++, performance, sdl-2, 2d-games

im trying to make 2d game like scorched earth:

and i need to work with pixels after some work the game running but i notice that `SDL_RenderDrawPoint()` making my game slower if  i use it.
and the `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()` not effect the memory like that

here some pictures and the code i run to make that conclusions.

this function only was for test if its slowing my game or not:

```
for (i = 0; i < ::g_SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ::g_SCREEN_WIDTH; j++)
    {
        if (map.at(i).at(j) == 1)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 50, 255, 90, 255);
            SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, j, i);
        }
        else
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
            SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, j, i);
        }
    }
}


SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
return;
```

[here the picture of what this code doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJhOH.jpg)

before this function the memory is 130 +- mb only
what can i do to make my game lightly like the original scorched earh or other game like liero?

Comment: It is extremely inefficient to render the whole frame one pixel at a time. If you need to build the frame pixel by pixel, it would probably be better to write to the `pixels` member of an [`SDL_Surface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) instead of calling `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` and `SDL_RenderDrawPoint`.

Comment: what can i do if i need some function to do pixel by pixel there is situations that i need to do that (like this circle)->https://images.app.goo.gl/p5Nigo3rcfzMMxsj8

Comment: (sorry for my bad english)   and other question when to use this function (SDL_RenderDrawPoint) and why this  function is not freeing memory after use? its my program problem or the function?

Comment: From looking at the SDL source code, if you're using a hardware renderer, it stores each individual draw command and change colour command in a big queue. This means if you're drawing 1920x1080 pixels, you're enqueueing 2 million draw and change colour commands. You'll get a better memory footprint if you switch to a software renderer, which just sets the pixel in a backbuffer (although you'll be severely limited in graphical performance).

Comment: If you must stick with drawing pixel-by-pixel on a hardware renderer, you can save a lot of memory by first setting the colour to green and drawing only the green points, then set the colour to white and draw all the white points.

Comment: @PopUp: If you want to render a circle whose pixel coordinates you calculate manually, you can also directly write to the `pixels` member of an [`SDL_Surface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface). For example, if you want to use the hardware renderer, you could first set the pixels of the surface to transparent and then write the individual pixels of the circle. You could then convert this `SDL_Surface` to an `SDL_Texture` using `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` (which transfers the pixel data to the graphics card) and blit it to the frame.